# SQL server Programming

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in my table. I am using sql server database

```
History_ID ID Changed_Field NewValue    Date
1          A  Owner         John        2015-01-01
2          A  Owner         Tom         2015-01-02
3          A  Status        New         2015-01-01
4          A  Status        Changed     2015-01-02
```

I want to convert this into following format. I would like to know what is the best way to do it. I tried unpivot the table it does not work. Any suggestions would be helpful. The data captures whenever there is a changed in the lead owner or status.

```
          ID  Owner   Status   Date
           A   John   New     2015-01-01
           A   Tom    Changed 2015-02-01
```

Comment: There can be more than one row per day? How to know which is connected to which? Maybe the IDs (and Date) are wrong in the example...

Comment: I have updated the dataset. There can be any type of change. Lead owner can be changes or lead status can be changed. I want to capture the current status of the lead and its owner.

Comment: If you are linking John to New and Tom to Changed via the date, you are going to end up with a lot of problems when you have two records with the same date. perhaps your IDs should have been A and B? Also using alpha ID's may be a bad idea, numeric ID's tend to have more options. Have you considered using an attribute table? That way you can assign a status to an owner via an ID and the ID can change when ever you need it to. in the event you need a Many to Many you can create a 3rd table that sits between owner and status.

Comment: What connects _John_ to _New_, and _Tom_ to _Changed_? As far as we can see it must be `Date`, but that should not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a pivot table query?

```html
select ID, [Owner], [Status], date
from (select * from YourTableName) as SourceTable
pivot 
 (max(NewValue)
 for Changed_Field in ([Owner], [Status])
 ) as PivotTable;
```

Which will give you this:

```
ID  Owner   Status  date  
A   John    New 2015-01-01  
A   Tom Changed 2015-01-02
```

Answer (score 2):

If your ID for Owner Tom (Line 2) and Status changed (line 4) were set to B rather than all of them A like this:

```
History_ID ID Changed_Field NewValue    Date
1          A  Owner         John        2015-01-01
2          B  Owner         Tom         2015-01-02
3          A  Status        New         2015-01-01
4          B  Status        Changed     2015-01-02
```

you could do the following:

```
Select 
  A.ID
, A.Changed_Field AS Owner
, (Select NewValue 
   FROM [table_name] 
   Where Date = A.Date
   AND ID = A.ID
   AND Changed_Field = 'Status') AS 'Status'
, A.Date
FROM [table_name] A
where A.Changed_Field = 'Owner'
```

Then your output will be like this:

```
ID  Owner   Status   Date
A   John    New     2015-01-01
B   Tom     Changed 2015-02-01
```

Comment: Why make runnable snippets? Just use the code formatting since you can't "run" SQL on here.

Comment: Sorry i haven't used the site in a while, still learning where everything is, i wanted to get him the info. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Much better :) A question though: Where do you get `AND Owner = A.Owner` from? There doesn't seem to be any column named `owner`

Comment: Its a typo! ill fix that too. That's what i get for writing this at the end of the day when i was packing up my stuff.